# React router hot-reload not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a small problem there are few similar questions on SA already but I can't figure out how to fix this. I am using `react-router-redux` but for this example I don't think there are any differences to using `react-router`

I have a simple setup:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/">
    <IndexRoute component={ItemList}/> 
    <Route path='item/:uuid' component={Item}/> 
  <Route>
<Router>
```

I am using:

- webpack
- webpack-dev-server
- html-webpack-plugin

When i visit localhost:8080 the IndexRoute is rendered. I can then press one of the items which has `onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(routeActions.push('/item/' + item.uuid))}` set. The history at this stage works fine I can go back and select another item and so on. But...

When I am on a item page for example localhost:8080/item/1234 and when I hit refresh I get:

`404 not found - localhost:8080/item/bundle.js`

This as well happens when I make some changes to the item page and hot reloading is rerendering it.

After going through few questions I can confirm that I have `historyApiFallback: true` and when I start the server it is reporting that `404s will fallback to /index.html`

**Update:**

So when I hit refresh after being on `localhost:8080/item/1234` chrome inspect say that was 200 response from server which looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Damage Increased</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then it is 404 on `http://localhost:8080/item/bundle.js`

It looks like all the dev server stuff is working fine and the server indeed returns the index file but then the `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` is looking for a `bundle.js` file inside of the `/item` sub.

Comment: have you got some repo with problem so we can look for issue?

Comment: I don't have anything at hand but I will set something up - it wont be till I get back home this evening.

Comment: ok just mention me or send me message so i can look up :)

Comment: cool updated with a response from the server it looks like the dev server stuff works fine - i will push to the repo as soon as I am back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Do:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Because when you access directly `/item/1234`, currently, you have a relative link to `bundle.js` so the browser will call `/item/bundle.js`.

If you're using `html-webpack-plugin`, you can add some rewrite rules to your dev-server (which you will have to add to your production one) - [see more here](http://jaketrent.com/post/pushstate-webpack-dev-server/)

Comment: this file is generated by html-webpack-plugin

Comment: @Kocur4d made some edits to my answer - your problem seems to be between the `html-webpack-plugin` and the config of your `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: yes it looks like as when i remove the /item from both routes and the push state action- and leave justa shallow mapping of /:uuid - it is all working fine. webpack have a publicPath option I try something with it. Never seen anyone mention publicPath before tho.

Comment: yes adding `output.publicPath = '/'` to webpack config fix the problem but I am not sure if this is how it needs to be done I never have to set publicPath before into my webpack config. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I don't use `html-webpack-plugin` or at least, I provide my own template which gives me full control above that kind of thing (in those cases, most of the time, it's either using hashHistory - so no problem of that kind - or [server-side rendering](https://github.com/topheman/react-es6-isomorphic/blob/master/server/views/layout.ejs) - so the html is rendered by the server based on a template)

Comment: ye I went a bit of a quick easy road with webpack setup - coming from ruby-on-rails the entire webpack adventure was like a black magic to me. Do you have any good resources on how to setup a universal react app something not too deep and considered best practices? As most of my projects now end up being two separate apps(react in front and rails-api in a backend) as there is so many resources out there on how to set it up that i got lost.

Comment: *easy road with webpack setup* > ;-) webpack docs is not the best one ever, lots of people get lost with it. Here are some resources that could be of some use for you [server-side rendering with react](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) - [webpack configuration](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto) + [some webpack tips](http://dev.topheman.com/tag/webpack/). Good luck @Kocur4d

Answer (score 1):

my problem was solved by adding `historyApiFallback: true` in `webpack.config` `devServer` section and `<base href="/">` in the head

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <base href="/">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link
     rel="stylesheet"
     type="text/css"
     href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top" >
   <div id="root"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.11.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>

 </html>
```

In this project, I used external resources such as `bootstrap` and some styles that were added in the head tag, as well as javascript files in the `index.html` file, but instead of this way it is better to add them in `package.json` and Imported in components.